# Is there a way to encode structural polymorphism in language nominal polymorphism type system?

Tags: c#, typescript, types, polymorphism

Is there a way to encode structural polymorphism like [type compatibility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) in TypeScript in language like C#?

Structural polymorphism is some thing like duck typing,
but limited to static type check, not run time error, example from TypeScript's doc:

```
interface Pet {
  name: string;
}
class Dog {
  name: string;
}
let pet: Pet;
// OK, because of structural typing
pet = new Dog();
```

thus `Dog` class does not required to explicit `extends Pet` interface.

C#'s linq syntax is a bit similar to structural polymorphism,
since `from x in value select x + 1;` only requires `value` object has `Select<int>` method, does not require a explicit `: IEnumerable<int>`,
and the check happens on compile time. But this feature can not be used for express general structural polymorphism.

References may be related to this:

Encoding should like [Encoding HKT in TypeScript](https://www.matechs.com/blog/encoding-hkts-in-typescript-once-again).

The Entity query in Unity DOTS(or many other ECS implementations) may be considered a limited version which only supports struct with fields limited to non-struct primitive type, the key is encoded by type, value type is component type.

Comment: By deriving from another class? `class Animal {}` and `class Dog : Animal {}`?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean by "structural polymorphism". As far as I can tell, `extends` is simply how typescript does inheritance, and that is supported in c# and most other object oriented languages.

Comment: I don't remember TypeScript `extends` being able to "encode structural polymophism". Maybe it's because I don't know what that term means, but if you could link a reference to that, it would be nice.

Comment: sorry for the misleading term, I've added more details and changed `extends`  into  more precise term `type compatibility`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to derive from a base class, e.g.:

```cs
class Animal {
    public virtual void MakeSound()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Animal doesn't know how to make a sound.");
    }
}

class Dog : Animal {
    public override void MakeSound()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Woof!");
    }
}

class Cat : Animal {
    public override void MakeSound()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Meow!");
    }
}

List<Animal> animals = new();
animals.Add(new Dog());
animals.Add(new Cat());

foreach (var animal in animals) {
    Console.WriteLine(animal.MakeSound());
}
```

Which should print `Woof!` and then `Meow!`.

Comment: sorry for the misleading question description. I've added more details. The explicit deriving via `: BaseClass` is exactly what I want to avoid. The objective is not about normal polymorphism in C# for some logic code, but for trying to lift design of archetype and component in ECS to type level.

Comment: Well, another way would to be do that with an interface, but you still derive from an interface in that case, which you want. I have never heard or seen anything like that in C#, since it is a statically typed language.